# suggestions on familarizing self with .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been reading a lot about .NET's step into the MVC framework.  I've tried the example applications too.  However, I've been a java programmer for a while.  So without having any knowledge of c# it gets difficult to understand the MVC applications.

What would you guys suggest is the best resource to get up and running with c# and then dive into the the cool MVC world.

For a long time, I've not liked ASP.net because of its cumbersome hoch poch structure.

Comment: Good question - probably one of our most popular. There are lots of duplicates, some quite recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head first C# is a very good book which you can go through, to get a good grasp on C# and once you've got the basics of C# right (which shouldn't take you long, since you come from a Java background), Go through [Stephen Walther's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/StephenWalther/), His blog is the best resource to learn ASP.NET MVC. Another good resource for learning ASP.NET MVC is the site http://www.asp.net/mvc, This site collects the aggregation of most of the resources on MVC, And lastly don't forget to watch the [dimecasts](http://dimecasts.net) (screencasts) for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Conery's [MVC storefront screencast series](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/?p=6) is excellent. He takes you through the entire process of building a functional MVC application with a focus on TDD and Agile design.

Also have a look at [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24504) - the complete source code is available.

Comment: Rob Conery has said that he will release the full source to the storefront, but he's still currently working on the project. The reason why I recommended it, is that the development methodology used is really excellent.

Comment: Actually the source code IS available, you can download it by going to http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: awesome Minhajuddin, nice find

Answer (score 0):

I find that video sessions, tutorials and articles work fine.  Until you start coding in the real world.

My recommendation would be start by creating a blog engine, it's simple and you will hit those edge cases that you won't see when following a book, video, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To start with C# I recommend you [.Net book Zero by Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html) (free)